# simple login php not working

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

Created a simple login form but it doesnt seem to work.It always opens the admin page.

```
$username=$_POST["username"];
$password=$_POST["password"];

if(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'",$con)){
session_start();
$_SESSION["username"]=$username;
$_SESSION["password"]=$password;
header('location:admin.html');
}
else{
echo "Login Failed.<a href=index.html>Re Login</a";
}
```

Need help.And here is the html part.

```
 <form method="post" id="loginform" action="validate.php">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label>Username :</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="username"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
<br>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label>Password :</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="password" name="password"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
<br>
    <tr>
        <td>
        <input type="submit" id="login" value="Log In" class="btn btn-primary"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="reset" id="reset" value="Reset" class="btn btn-primary"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Need the working code in 2hrs else im dommed

Comment: Any error..? if you enter username or password first time , session's set and you can enter the page .

Comment: You're just checking if the query ran successfully, you're not checking if you actually get any rows of users returned from the select. Also, please use prepared/parameterized queries to mitigate sql injection hacks. And you should use PHPs native `password_hash` http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php api to hash passwords (never store plain text passwords).

Comment: This code is extremely bad and insecure, it's wide open to SQL injection, and it relies on the mysql_ functions which are no longer available in the latest versions of PHP.  Also I don't see anywhere in your code where you're actually opening a connection to a database.

Comment: `mysql_query()` returns false ONLY on error. Use `mysql_num_rows()` function to check whether the SELECT query returns any row or not. And please don't use `mysql_` functions, they are deprecated as of PHP 5.5 and are removed altogether in PHP 7.0. Use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)**

> For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN and other statements returning
>   resultset, mysql_query() returns a resource on success, or FALSE on
>   error.

Use **[mysql_num_rows()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php)**

> Retrieves the number of rows from a result set.

```
$result = mysql_query(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'",$con));
$row = mysql_num_rows($result);
if ($row > 0) {
   header('location:admin.html');

} else {
echo "Login Failed.<a href=index.html>Re Login</a";

}
```

> **Note**
>
> Mysql is deprecated instead use mysqli or PDO

Don't store plain password into database use hashing technic

http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php

To prevent from sql injection check [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)?